# Get a list of object with thymeleaf

Tags: forms, jsp, spring-mvc, thymeleaf

I am trying to get the values in a form with thymeleaf. The form is a table with several  that represent one row of a CallDataRecord. The behavior I'm looking for is to get the CallDataRecord that contains the list of each element.

This is my controller :

```
@RequestMapping(value="/usage", method=RequestMethod.POST)
public ModelAndView usageSubmit(@ModelAttribute CallDataRecord cdr, ModelAndView mav) {
    System.out.println(cdr.getRecords().size());
    return mav;
}
```

The object source :

```
public class CallDataRecord {
    private ArrayList<CallDataRecordLine> records;
    ... 
}

public class CallDataRecordLine {
    String chargedQuantity;
    String fromNumber;
    String toNumber;
    String dt;
    String usage;
}
```

And my associated jSP

```
<form action="#" th:action="@{/usage}" th:object="${cdr}" method="post">
    <tr id='addr0'>
        <th:block th:each="calldatarecordline : ${cdr.records}">
            <td>1</td>
            <td><input type="text"  th:field="${calldatarecordline.fromNumber}" name='fromNumber'
                            placeholder='+555...' class="form-control" /></td>
            <td><input type="text" name='toNumber' th:field="${calldatarecordline.toNumber}" placeholder='+555...'
                            class="form-control" /></td>
            <td>
                <div class='input-group date'>
                    <input name='date' type="text" th:field="${calldatarecordline.dt}" class="form-control"><span
                                    class="input-group-addon"><i
                                    class="glyphicon glyphicon-th"></i></span>
                            </div>
                        </td>
            <td><input type="text" name='duration' th:field="${calldatarecordline.usage}" class="form-control" /></td>
                        <td><select class="form-control" name='usageType'>
                                <option value="value1">Message</option>
                                <option value="value2">Data</option>
                                <option value="value3">Call</option>
                        </select></td>
        </th:block>
    </tr>
</form>
```

At the end, I fetch my CallDataRecord, the list inside is instanciated but empty so it doesn't work as expected.
I tried to retrieve only one CallDataRecordLine in another JSP and it works fine. So the problem is the iteration on the list.

Thanks for your time

Answer (score 0):

So couple things:

1. You are generating columns not rows of data (just making sure that is what you are after)
2. change all instances of th:field="${}" to th:field="*{}" and remove calldatarecordline (check out e.g. below)

   input type="text"  th:field="*{fromNumber}" name='fromNumber' placeholder='+555...' class="form-control"

You are already setting the object to be calldatarecordline for the whole section no point calling it again.

EDIT 1: Rewrite of code to be able to iterate

```
<form action="#" th:action="@{/usage}" th:object="${cdr}" method="post">
    <table id='addr0'>
        <tr th:each="calldatarecordline : ${cdr.records}">
            <td>1</td>
            <td>
                <input type="text" th:field="*{fromNumber}" name='fromNumber'
                       placeholder='+555...' class="form-control"/>
            </td>
            <td>
                <input type="text" name='toNumber' th:field="*{toNumber}"
                       placeholder='+555...' class="form-control"/>
            </td>
            <td>
                <div class='input-group date'>
                    <input name='date' type="text" th:field="*{dt}" class="form-control">
                    <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-th"></i></span>
                </div>
            </td>
            <td><input type="text" name='duration' th:field="*{usage}" class="form-control"/></td>
            <td>
                <select class="form-control" name='usageType'>
                    <option value="value1">Message</option>
                    <option value="value2">Data</option>
                    <option value="value3">Call</option>
                </select>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</form>
```

Comment: 1. th:field are columns yes, it will represent attributes of my CallDataRecordLine. What I'm looking for is for each <tr> (nested in <th:block th:each="calldatarecordline : ${cdr.records}"> ) I want to create a new CallDataRecordLine that will be pass through the object th:object="${cdr}" This object is a CallDataRecord that contains a List<CallDataRecordLine>.

    2. I tried to update my code with the new syntax but I still end up with an empty list. I think my mistake could be in the declaration of th:object or th:each

Comment: When I switch the object to a CallDataRecordLine, it works, I pass into the constructor and get the input values. When I go for the CallDataRecord, it passes through the constructor so I get  a List<CallDataRecordLine> but it never passed into the CallDataRecordLine constructor. therefore I have an empty list.

Comment: ok i rewrote your form to be able to create rows of data, try it and let me know

Comment: Thanks, I update the form but I'm still end up with an empty List. Again on debug mode I am going into the constructor of CallDataRecord, but never inside the constructor of CallDataRecordLine...

Comment: is the controller you your question the one you use to call this code?

Comment: Yes it is, as i said if i update my code from _public ModelAndView usageSubmit(@ModelAttribute CallDataRecord cdr_ to _public ModelAndView usageSubmit(@ModelAttribute CallDataRecordLine cdr_ and I remove the th:each stuff in the form, I manage to fetch my object, so it look like it works..